# How to redirect a new page (wrong URL) to another page?

Tags: .htaccess, url, html, redirect

I'm new at programming. We have an office project, the website's URL is `www.project.com.ph` (sample name), this is already a live website from the client. But the released printouts have the instructions for the users to go to `www.project.com/ph` which is wrong and we can't reprint the material since it already reached plenty of event places.

Now the problem is, we need to redirect to `www.project.com.ph` automatically if the users type in the browser's address bar `www.project.com/ph`. I ask if this is possible without any kind of CMS or Wordpress and how to actually do it? We bought a new domain `www.project.com` for this. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following near the top of your `.htaccess` file in the root of `www.project.com`. This works OK (although marginally less efficient) if both domains are pointing to the same place, since it specifically checks that we are requesting the "wrong" domain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?project\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ph/?(.*) http://www.project.com.ph/$1 [NC,R=302,L]
```

This will redirect requests for `www.project.com/ph` (no slash), `www.project.com/ph/` (with a trailing slash) and `www.project.com/ph/<whatever>` to `http://www.project.com.ph/<whatever>`.

This is a temporary (302) redirect. Change it to a permanent (301) only when you are sure it's working OK.

Answer (score 1):

From kj.'s answer on a similar question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522921/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-to-single-page)

In your .htaccess for www.project.com, this should do the trick.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.project.com.ph/ [R=permanent,NC,L]
```

This will redirect any request to project.com to the domain `http://www.project.com.ph/`

To include the path after the `/ph`/` you can use this.

```
RewriteEngine on
# redirect including path after ph/ (e.g. project.com/ph/directory/file.php to project.com.ph/directory/file.php
RewriteRule ^ph/(.*)$ http://www.project.com.ph/$1 [R=permanent,NC,L]
# redirect any other requests to project.com.ph index
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.project.com.ph/ [R=permanent,NC,L]
```

Comment: Another question, would this apply if project.com.ph has multiple subpages like for example, www.project.com.ph/sub/1234, www.project.com.ph/sub/5678, etc.? Or is this a new kind of situation that needs another solution? Thank you!

Comment: Also worth noting, if both domains are using the same hosting, you will need to define the full original URL such as in N.Danielprabhakaran's answer. Or, use a rewrite condition before every rule. `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.project.com$`

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect (301 redirect) the URL using RewritrRule in .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule "http://www.project.com/ph/(.*)" "http://www.project.com.ph/$1" [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: This has a few errors... The URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ does not include the hostname (so this will never match). The _substitution_ is missing the _scheme_, so will be seen as a relative URL-path (which would result in a malformed redirect). The backreference is also missing from the _substitution_ (which I assume you were intending to use since you have a capturing group in the _pattern_ and it's not so useful without it).