# All pages redirect to single page - Too many redirect wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I tried to redirect all the pages to one page. I got the solution from the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522921/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-to-single-page) in Stack overflow but I'm getting `Too many redirects` error. Here is my code:

```
Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/closing-down$ 
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^my\.ip\.11\.11
RewriteRule $ /closing-down [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your rule to this:

```
Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/closing-down[\s?] [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^my\.ip\.11\.11
RewriteRule ^ /closing-down [R=302,L]
```

And test this in new browser to avoid old cache.

Using `THE_REQUEST` instead of `REQUEST_URI` as `REQUEST_URI` may change to `/index.php` after WP default rule whereas `THE_REQUEST` remains unchanged for a web request.

Comment: But I took the code from accepted answer in the forum why it's not working for me?

Comment: That answer may not be using WP I have already given you reason why `REQUEST_URI` doesn't work.

Comment: Got it. Could you please add except for static file like css. It might help others.thanks

Comment: Added `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` to exclude static files.